# How do i find when a partial load starts and finishes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have the following partials called from the main view `Super1.cshtml` view.

`Super1.cshtml` has a call to call the container partial

**Super1.cshtml**

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("_ContainerPartial")
<div>
```

**_ContainerPartial.cshtml**

```
<div>
   @Html.Partial("_Partial1")
<div>

<div>
@Html.Partial("_Partial2")
<div>
```

in `_Partial2.cshtml` i have placed a `div` that will be later loaded with a `jstreeview` control or `bootstrap` tree

**_Partial2.cshtml**

```
<div id="treeviewHolder">

</div>
```

**_Partial1.cshtml**

```
<div id="otherInputControls">
@*in this section there are devexpress controls that will get loaded with server data*@
</div>
```

In the main view `"Super1.cshtml"` i have added a `javascript` script block (note: this is not a `@Section scripts{ }` section this just a main `javascript` block)

here is my `javascript` block in the main view

```
 <script>
        @{
            //Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["TemplateTypeID"]);
            int i = (int)Mercury.Util.TemplateTypeEnum.SocialHistory;
            //int y = Convert.ToInt32(RouteData.Values["TemplateTypeID"]);
            var pID = ((LoggedUserInfo)Session["LoggedUserInfo"]).PartyID;
            var temp = new Mercury.BL.XmlNodeWrapperCollection();
            var xDoc = temp.GetItems( (Mercury.Util.TemplateTypeEnum)i, pID );//xml document si ready
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            alert($('.tree li:has(ul)').length);

            //write code to check what time each partial gets loaded //(loading completion time) and based on completion add some contents to the //<div> in _partial2.cshtml

        });
</script>
```

what i want to know is, how do i find when the partial `_Partial2.cshtml` gets loaded? The reason for this is, after the load completion of **Partial2** i need to load some other elements to the **_Partial2**

Comment: You're mixing 2 different things here. By the time your `<script>` runs, all `Partials` were already loaded because you're already in the realm of client-side. The actual inclusion of the partial using `Html.Partial()` is performed by the MVC framework *on the server side*. The only time you'll have to "check what time each partial gets loaded" is if those partials were loaded separately (typically using AJAX).

Comment: @haim770 assume there are no ajax calls, in a case like this how would i use ajax to check the loading times

Comment: @haim770 if the partials should be loaded before running the scripts, then thats where my problem is, there is no div of the second partial

Comment: @haim770 you answer with checking ajax worked, please post as answer if require merits : )

Answer (score 0):

Load both partial views separately using Jquery Ajax call in document.ready()

That is the best way you can manage the sequence.